# How to count the occurrence of a particular word with edge cases in Python

Tags: python

I have written the code to count the occurrence of a certain word cat in it, the code is passing only some of my test cases, it is not passing all the test, especially the edge cases. Please note am not allowed to use inbuilt functions like count() and a whole host of others.
Here is my code:

```
mystery_string = "my cat your cat"
splitword = mystery_string.split()
sum = 0
for string in splitword:
    if string == "cat":
        sum += 1
print (sum)
```

when i change the variable mystery_string to  `mystery_string = "catcatcatcatcat!!".` or `mystery_string = "cacacat cacacat"` or this one `mystery_string = "ucatX"` or even this  `mystery_string = ".$cacacatcatcat".` the code just breaks. i have researched stackoverflow for similar problem but no solution.

Comment: That is because `string.split()` splits a string using whitespace. In your edge cases like `"cacacat cacacat"`, the only whitespace is between the two words.

Comment: Does `catacat` count as 2 occurrences or 1? You can use `in` instead of `==` if that is just `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [count](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method of strings.

```
>>> "catcatcatcatcat!!".count("cat")
5
```

Or, using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> len(re.findall("cat", "catcatcatcatcat!!"))
5
```

Comment: How about regular expressions?

Comment: Thanks your solution is working but i was asked to use a loop

Comment: Can you modify my loop to provide an answer for me please sorry for being a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is the ".count(str)" function
Ex:

```
catcatcat!ccat".count("cat")
```

Outputs 4
But if you don't want to use it you can do the following

```
def count(mainstr, substr):
 thecount = 0
 for i in range(len(mainstr)):
  if i <= len(mainstr) - len(substr):
   if mainstr[i:i+len(substr)] == substr:
    thecount+=1
 return thecount
```

Your code counts the occurrence of a word in a text but not the occurrence of a word in a string...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can't i resolve this problem without using an inbuilt function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can't i resolve this problem without using an inbuilt function.

Comment: @ Nacho can you walk me through your second function, were exactly can i pass in my variable.

Comment: @Emmanuel ogbonna well you just have to copy my function in your code and then you can do print(count("my cat your cat", "cat")) (You have to do this after the declaration of the function, in other words, you have to paste the function and some lines of code after the function you can do that)

Comment: @ Nacho thanks once more for the effort but, my instructor asked me not to use any inbuilt function like the count() function you used in the print statement. I don't know if there is a work around with my own code or a code without a built in function.

Comment: Well you could just remove the line saying def and the line saying return then unident and then write before the code mainstr = mystery_string and in other line substr = "cat"

Comment: @ Nacho am officially lost, please am a beginner in python just taking an introductory course, could you make your solution more descriptive, say modifying the code yourself. thanks a lot for the effort, so sorry to bother you.